# How to specify endpoint configuration for server using Java omniorb

Tags: java, corba

How to specify endpoint configuration for server using Java.
I am using omniorb.

I tried below:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "someip");
    ORB orb = ORB.init(args, p);
```

But still its picking the local host ip.

Is there a way we can pass an argument to configure the ip.

Can I use org.omg.CORBA.ORBListenEndpoints?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for down voting this question

Comment: Your question shows no research effort, and is not really understandable out of context. Provide more details. What have you tried? Does the configuration options not provide what you want? Is this a coding problem?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (if that applies to you) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and *improve your question*.

Comment: I am trying to configure the java server to run on specific ip and port, I used org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost in orb.propertirs and tried reading this and setting the value read in orb_init, but still the server is running on ip  localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Your definitely not using omniorb and Java. Omniorb is a C++ ORB

For Java build-in JDK ORB, try

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    args[0] = "com.sun.CORBA.ORBServerHost";
    args[1] = "someip";
    ORB orb = ORB.init(args, p);
```

Note: works on cmdline via `-Dcom.sun.CORBA.ORBServerHost=someip`.
But does not work as property!

Comment: Did you mean your 2nd and 3rd lines to set a key-value pair on your `Properties` object, p? Setting the args[] this way doesn't work for me, but putting those same values into Properties does.